# How do I store the result of sql without column name in php variable?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I’m trying to sore the result of sql in a variable. following is the sql(eloquent) :

```
$key = $request->input('product_key'); // from previous page
$category_id = ProductModel::select(‘category_id’)->where(‘product_id’, $key)->get();

echo $category_id;
```

but when i echo it , the output looks like [{“category_id”:301}]

i want only 301 to gets save in variable so that i can use it further ??

Basically i want to get all the products who's category_id is same as that of a given product. Note i have only prodcut_id.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: The output looks like an array of hashes. You could just output or store the value of each hash in your array after you requested it from the db.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are refering to the `value` method. Find more about it here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#retrieving-results

> If you don't even need an entire row, you may extract a single value from a record using the value method. This method will return the value of the column directly:

example usage from the docs

`$email = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');`

Answer (score 0):

Try using Eloquent's `pluck` method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-pluck

```
$key = $request->input('product_key');
$category_id = ProductModel::where('product_id', $key)->pluck('category_id')->all();
echo $category_id;
```

This should result in an array with a single element, which is the `category_id` you search for (or more elements in case `key` matches more than one row, but only values as you want).